# How to call javascript function from code behind on button click and store its output and proceed further

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My javascript code:

```
   function Confirm()
    {
     var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
     confirm_value.type = "hidden";
     confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

     if (confirm("UserID already exists...Do you want to update            information?"))
      {
         confirm_value.value = "Yes";
      }

     else
      {
          confirm_value.value = "No";
       }

            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
     }
```

My asp.net code on button click:

```
         protected void Btn_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               bool check;
               _objClsCreateUsers = new ClsCreateUsers();

                check = _objClsCreateUsers.CheckUserID(Txt_UserID.Text);

              if (check == true)
               {
                     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,                        this.GetType(),            "alertMessage", "Confirm();", true);
                    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];

             if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                {

                    _objClsCreateUsers.UpdateData(Txt_UserID.Text,    Txt_UserName.Text,               Txt_Password.Text, Lst_Department.Text,                                                   Convert.ToDateTime(Txt_ExpiredOn.Text),    Convert.ToBoolean(Lst_IsAdmin.Text));
                   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,                                                                this.GetType(),                                                                          "alertMessage", "alert('Record Updated Successfully')", true);
                ClearAll();
enter code here
            }
            else
            {
                Txt_UserID.Text = "";
            }
        }

        else
        {
            _objClsCreateUsers.InsertData(Txt_UserID.Text, Txt_UserName.Text, Txt_Password.Text, Lst_Department.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(Txt_CreatedOn.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(Txt_ExpiredOn.Text), Convert.ToBoolean(Lst_IsAdmin.Text));
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('User Created Successfully')", true);
            ClearAll();
        }
    }
```

I am having problem in catching the output value of javascript function's output.

Javascript runs after the complete code of button click is run. I want it to run in the middle of code.

Thanks.

Comment: trying doing the opposite... call code behind function via jquery ajax... kindly refer http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/01/02/calling-asp-net-code-behind-using-jquery-ajax-simple-complete-example/

Comment: This is not the way HTTP works. You will have to make a different request each time. You cannot process at server side get value from Client browser and process server side code again.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it's a create account kind of form, An ideal way as per me should be as below

You should make an ajax call when the value in the UserID textbox is changed. Or Bind Server side event for the text control (hope you are using server controls). In this AJAX call you can get the result from server if the user id already exists or not and show the message at the same time itself.

On submit, you should again check if the user ID already exists, and update the information straightforward without confirmation. If the ID does not exists then Insert it